Rust Firebase Messaging registration id?
I'm starting to build a service in Rust that publishes Firebase messages and plan on using the fcm crate (https://docs.rs/fcm/latest/fcm/).
I'm confused as to what the registration id is? I don't see that in the cloud console.
Thanks for your help
let client = fcm::Client::new();

let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("message", "Howdy!");

let mut builder = fcm::MessageBuilder::new("<Registration ID>", "<registration id>"); **// What is the registration id?**
builder.data(&map);

let response = client.send(builder.finalize()).await?;
println!("Sent: {:?}", response);


It's an array of registration tokens. And you get the token by calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() or Firebase.messaging.token
In your Rust code, replace <Registration ID> with the actual registration token obtained from your client app.

config from node: fcmMessengerSettings: { "type": "service_account", "project_id": "project_id", "private_key_id": "private_key_id", "private_key": "private_key", "client_email": "client_email", "client_id": "client_id", "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs", "client_x509_cert_url": "cert_url", "universe_domain": "googleapis.com" }

Thank you @Jack ! I'm getting an Unauthorized error from the fcm sdk in Rust. I'm able to publish from Node successfully. In Node, I pass in quite a bit more info to firebase but in the fcm client it's only asking for the api key and registration key. I don't see a way to pass project_id, client_id, etc. to Rust. Is this not required? Any ideas as to why I'm getting the unauthorized error?

The fcm crate you have used is using legacy api which will be sunset by the end of next month.
